# How to write OrientDB update query with Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, orientdb

I have repository and update method:

```
public interface TestRepo extends OrientObjectRepository<Test>
{
    @Query("UPDATE Test t SET t.a = :a WHERE t.b = :b")
    void updateTest(
            @Param("b") String b, @Param("a") int a);
}
```

If I run this update method and I get `IllegalArgumentException`. Most likely my query is incorrect for OrientDb.
So is there any tutorial how to write update query with Spring Data?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change your query in this way (by removing the `t` variable):

```
UPDATE Test SET a = :a WHERE b = :b
```

**EDITED**

you can try to add `@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)` in this way:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Test t SET t.a = :a WHERE t.b = :b")
void updateTest(
        @Param("b") String b, @Param("a") int a);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @Orest, are `a` and `b` the name of the fields of your class ?

Comment: Not working. Maybe it connected to my "b" field value I have urls like "http ://google.com". Maybe you know if OrientDb save values with colon without any problems?

Comment: Hi @Orest, I have to check. Do you have the entire error log ?